# Importing xml file in MS Excel - How can we automate this flow using Python or any other programming language?

Tags: java, python, xml, automation, xlsx

I want to automate the process of importing XML file data in MS Excel using Python or any other programming language or by any other method which is possible. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python programming languages `pandas` library can facilitate in this. Once you get the XML into a `DataFrame`, there's a method that facilitates saving the `DataFrame` to Excel format (or at least CSV).

This is a comprehensive guide on XML to Excel conversion in Python [here](https://ajalacomfort.com/python-4-beginners-xml-to-excel-within-a-minute/)

If you want to do this in Java, the Apache POI library is very useful. A short guide is available [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microsoft-excel)

There's quite a few ways to get this done, depending on the language used.

Comment: If you feel that my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green check mark to the left. This will ensure that others looking for the same information will be able to find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is mentioned in the steps below:

- Imports required library
- read and parse XML file from the path
- extract the root element
- make a map after finding the required elements from the root elements
- create Excel file from the created map object
- save that file to the destined path
- close all the stream if any remain opened.

Now code the above steps in any prefer language python, java, or any other.